# FacebookAuthorizeFilter endless redirect

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add facebook login to my application. To that extent I'm using a following snippet of code:

```
    [FacebookAuthorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

And I register a filter **FacebookAuthorizeFilter**.

When I navigate to /Home/About what I get is an endless redirect to

```
/Home/About?code=AQAPoxl1J-.......
```

I can login using facebook if I just use OAuth provided in ASP.NET MVC4 project template.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours spent debugging, reflecting, source-code analyzing I came to the conclusion that **FacebookAuthorizeAttribute** and **FacebookAuthorizeFilter** can only meaningfully be used in a Facebook Canvas application.

Comment: I'm running up against the same problem. Do you remember why this was the case?

Answer (score 1):

I delved into the FacebookAuthorize filter code more. The reason the Filter does not work with non-canvas applications is that inside the filter's OnAuthorization method the the method is relying on Facebook's signed_request being present in the POST requset when the user is redirected back to your application. If signed_request is never present the filter will continue to redirect:

...code omitted...

```
        if (signedRequest == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            // Cannot obtain user information from signed_request, redirect to Facebook OAuth dialog.
            string redirectUrl = GetRedirectUrl(request);
            Uri loginUrl = client.GetLoginUrl(redirectUrl, _config.AppId, null);
            filterContext.Result = CreateRedirectResult(loginUrl);
        }
```

...code omitted..

An alternative approach may be to create a similar filter that checks for the existent of the code query string parameter. Once code is obtained you may use your application's appId and appSecret to exchange the code for an access token. Once the access token is obtained you may determine which permissions the user has granted and process appropriately.